# Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function' while converting java interface override method to kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am trying to convert a java function to its kotlin counterpart but I am getting `Modifier 'override' is not applicable to 'local function'` at `override fun binderDied()`.
This is the java code:

```java
private void linkToDeath(IBinder service) {
    try {
        service.linkToDeath(new IBinder.DeathRecipient() {
            @Override
            public void binderDied() {
                Log.d(TAG, "======binderDied======");
                deviceServiceEngine = null;
                bindDeviceService();
            }
        }, 0);
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the kotlin conversion that is complaining at `override fun binderDied()`

```kotlin
private fun linkToDeath(service: IBinder) {
    try {
        service.linkToDeath(IBinder.DeathRecipient {
            override fun binderDied() {
                Log.d(TAG, "======binderDied======")
                deviceServiceEngine = null
                bindDeviceService()
            }
        }, 0)
    } catch (e: RemoteException) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Java version has an anonymous class implementation of the interface (I'm assuming it's an interface and not a class). To do this in Kotlin, you need to precede it with `object:` like this:

```
private fun linkToDeath(service: IBinder) {
    try {
        service.linkToDeath(object: IBinder.DeathRecipient {
            override fun binderDied() {
                Log.d(TAG, "======binderDied======")
                deviceServiceEngine = null
                bindDeviceService()
            }
        }, 0)
    } catch (e: RemoteException) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If this interface is a functional interface (only one abstract method), then you can use lambda syntax instead of an anonymous class:

```
private fun linkToDeath(service: IBinder) {
    try {
        service.linkToDeath(IBinder.DeathRecipient {
            Log.d(TAG, "======binderDied======")
            deviceServiceEngine = null
            bindDeviceService()
        }, 0)
    } catch (e: RemoteException) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You got that error because without `object:` you were using the lambda syntax, so your inner function was parsed as a locally defined function within the lambda function.